# Background image in android application

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating an android application, using jQuery mobile and phone gap.

I would likes to add a back ground image to the application. I did some thing like this

```
<head>

body {
background-url:("bg.png") left top no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin : 0;
padding:0;
}

</head>
<body></body>
```

Its working fine in device already .. But in some devices its only showing the part of the background image....

Any one please help me to make the image fit the screen.. I am very new to mobile application. Please help.. I created the image in 480px X 800px dimensions.

Thanks in advance